# Undefined reference in wbchar.h

Tags: c

I use the file "wbchar.h" in my project, but when i compile it this error appears in is_basic function:

> undefined reference to `is_basic_table`

the error is in the line 438 of this file
http://www.koders.com/c/fid74476D4B812D46517B68E4BA9E3F52F4EB82F2CD.aspx

Why this error is raised?

EDIT: "mbchar.h"

Answer (score 4):

This error is raised because `is_basic_table` is declared in `wbchar.h`, but not defined (because of `extern`):

```
extern unsigned int is_basic_table[]; /* At line 433. */
```

The definition of `is_basic_table` is in some other source file. You must link with the object that contains the definition of `is_basic_table` or compile its source into your binary (I do not know what the source file is that contains the definition of `is_basic_table`).

Answer (score 0):

@hmjd is correct.

The definition of `is_basic_table` is in `mbchar.c`:

http://www.koders.com/c/fidE57932491F3B2834B669201F4619CF24BAB86BDE.aspx

```
#if IS_BASIC_ASCII

/* Bit table of characters in the ISO C "basic character set".  */
unsigned int is_basic_table [UCHAR_MAX / 32 + 1] =
{
  0x00001a00,       /* '\t' '\v' '\f' */
  0xffffffef,       /* ' '...'#' '%'...'?' */
  0xfffffffe,       /* 'A'...'Z' '[' '\\' ']' '^' '_' */
  0x7ffffffe        /* 'a'...'z' '{' '|' '}' '~' */
  /* The remaining bits are 0.  */
};

#endif /* IS_BASIC_ASCII */
```

The constant `IS_BASIC_ASCII` is set on `mbchar.h`.

You can `#include "mbchar.c"` to get that, but be warned that more conflicts can arise.